# Rocky Linux 8 SSH Sessions Timing Out

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, redhat-enterprise-linux, openssh

I am connecting via SSH from PuTTY running on Windows 10 to an OpenSSH server on Rocky Linux 8. I am using the **Bash** shell. These sessions close after a period of inactivity. I have not measured the timeout, but it seems to be on the order of a small number of hours. I am trying to understand how these sessions are being closed. I will explain below the potential causes I've ruled out.

### sshd_config ClientAliveInterval

**/etc/ssh/sshd_config** has `ClientAliveInterval` set to **0**.

### Bash Environment Variable TMOUT

I have searched for `TMOUT` in all regular files in the entire file system. This environment variable is not set anywhere.

### Network Infrastructure

It occurred to me that perhaps a firewall sitting between my client and server might be monitoring connections and actively closing (via  TCP **FIN**, perhaps) those that have been idle for some time. I have ruled out this possibility by noting that sessions from the same Windows host to other Linux hosts (not Rocky 8) do not close. These other hosts are behind the same firewall as the problematic Rocky 8 host and also have `ClientAliveInterval` and `TMOUT` set as described above.

### Request for Help

What other mechanisms might be closing sessions due to inactivity?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly happening because the connection is idle and the TCP stack is resetting the idle connection.  It may be that other Linux distributions set these values differently or are using different kernel versions with different settings, which is why you're only seeing a problem with Rocky Linux 8.

The solution here is to set `ClientAliveInterval` to something nonzero. 30, for example, would be a fine value.  While this seems counterintuitive, this causes data to be sent on an otherwise idle channel, preventing the OS from closing the connection.  Now, if the connection drops for whatever reason, that will be detected sooner than before, but you would have dropped the connection anyway, and there's no way to avoid that being detected sooner or later.